# Rerender another component when the state is changed

Tags: reactjs

I want to rerender my another component when the state is changed. I've conditional components. One of them is related to input in my main component. It is rendered in the first place but I cant rerender it when I change the input value (also state value). The component is `SearchGifList`

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import TrendingGifList from './TrendingGifList';
import SearchGifList from './SearchGifList';



class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        value: '',
        search: false
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      search : true,
    })
  }
  getTrendingGifs = () => {
    this.setState({
      search : false,
      value: ''
    })
  }

  getComponent = () => {
    if(this.state.search) {
      return <SearchGifList value={this.state.value} />
    }
    else {
      return <TrendingGifList />
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>    
            <div>
                <a onClick={this.getTrendingGifs}>Logo</a>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                  <input className="input-search" type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                  <button type="submit" >Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div>
                {this.getComponent()}
            </div>
      </>
    ); 
  }
}

export default App;
```

SearchGifList Component code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Masonry from 'react-masonry-css';
import {API_KEY, API_URL_search} from './constants'

class SearchGifList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          error: null,
          isLoaded: false,
          items: [],
          breakpointColumnsObj : {
            default: 4,
            1100: 3,
            700: 2,
            500: 1
            },
            offset: 0,
            limit: 20,
            api_key: API_KEY,
            total_count: 0,
            value: this.props.value
        };
      }


    searchGifs = () => {
      fetch( API_URL_search + 
      "?q=" + this.state.value +
      "&api_key=" + this.state.api_key + 
      "&limit=" +  this.state.limit +
      "&offset=" + this.state.offset)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(
            (result) => {
                this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                items: (this.state.items).concat(result.data),
                total_count: result.pagination.total_count,
                offset : this.state.offset + 20
              });

            },
            (error) => {
              this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                error : 'Somethings went wrong to search gifs.'
              });
            }
          )
    }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.searchGifs();
      }

      loadMore = () => {
        if(this.state.offset < this.state.total_count){
          this.setState({
            offset : this.state.offset + 20
          });
        }
        this.searchGifs();
      }


    render() {
        const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
        if (error) {
        return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
        } else if (!isLoaded) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
        } else {
        return (
            <>

                <Masonry
                breakpointCols={this.state.breakpointColumnsObj}
                className="my-masonry-grid"
                columnClassName="my-masonry-grid_column"
                >
                    {items.map(item => (
                        <div className="gif-container" >
                            <img className="gif-preview" height={item.images.fixed_width.height} src={item.images.fixed_width.webp} alt="giphy baby" />
                        </div>

                    ))}
                </Masonry>

                <button onClick={this.loadMore}>Load More</button>
            </>
        );
        }
    }

}

export default SearchGifList;
```

Comment: Is `SearchGifList` the component that is not being rendered? If it is the case, can you share its code?

Comment: wild guess: `SearchGifList` makes search only on `componentDidMount` and does not care if `value` prop is updated later

Comment: @skyboyer that is true, but if I delete it, it is not working. I added the SearchGifList component code too.

Answer (score 0):

It should render content after changing state. Here is an similar example I have created for you now. https://codesandbox.io/embed/example-ys041

Please check it I think that will help you a lot.

If still you are not getting any idea then send me the your example via codesandbox I will check it for you.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I couldnt find the answer:( Props is ok for SearchGifList, but I couldnt find a way to call searchGifs() method ever time that props is changed. It is wrong about SearchGifsList component probably.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem `componentDidUpdate()` method:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.props.value !== prevProps.value) {

          setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
            items: [],
            offset: 0
          }, function(){
            this.searchGifs();
            });
          }, 10)

        }
      }
```

Thank you for all answers